# "Определение коня в вакууме" или "Определение коней в вакууме"?

Tags: грамотная-речь

Есть выражение: **определение стола**. Оно описывает, что за предмет- стол. Благодаря этому можно выделить все предметы под названием **стол** - **столы**.

Грамотно ли говорить **определение столов**?

Comment: Наверное не определение стола, а понятие. Понятие Столы особое: оно не описывает все столы.

Comment: "Понятие столы" особое, но речь про другую фразу "понятие столов". В том смысле, что все столы имеют одно и то же понятие - понятие имеемое столами - понятие столов. Например, в таком контексте "Понятие столов слишком раздутое." вместо "Понятие стола слишком раздутое."

Comment: «Объём понятия «дерево» это множество всех деревьев, которые существовали, существуют или будут существовать; реальных и воображаемых, множество всех разновидностей деревьев.» Как у понятия «стол», у него бесконечный объём. А у понятия «столы» объём может быть и ограниченный, к примеру, когда столы обеденные. (https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Понятие)

Answer (score 1):

**Определение стола** отделяет множество столов от множества не-столов (стульев, кресел и так далее). По аналогии: «определение рационального числа», но «определение *множества* рациональных чисел».

**Определение столов** — ответ на вопрос «Что такое столы?» — и тут уже не очень понятно, о чём речь: о том, что такое стол, или о том, какие подмножества есть в множестве столов (чем письменные отличаются от обеденных, а те — от хирургических), или просто о любой совокупности двух и более предметов типа «стол», чем бы они ни были.